# How do I supposed to run Nginx + Django site connected together by UNIX socket?

Tags: nginx, django, fastcgi

```
runfcgi.py:18: RemovedInDjango19Warning: FastCGI support has been deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9.
```

What to use instead? I don't want Nginx and Django site to share user account, chroot and other things and want a UNIX socket between them.

Is there any supported way to run Django disjointed from the web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move to uWSGI instead http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html